# Google Analytics Filter for Network Domain at Profil Level

Tags: google-analytics

I am getting a lot of traffic scraping my site at the moment from a particular domain, which we are having issues blocking using htaccess as they do not pass an IP address.

As such i want to create a profile filter in GA to block the traffic, but im a bit confused.

In the reporting suite of GA the domain I want can only be found in the Network Domain dimension, however in profile level filters this isnt an option, does anyone know what the best filter to use would be

ISP Organisation or ISP Domain, this seems to be a undocumented as far as I can tell

Cheers

John

Comment: This question is not so much about programming but about managing a site and belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: My bad sorry, didn't know of that site. Will join up.

Comment: no prob, they accept formats for different questions. I've written an answer here that has some "code" but it's really just a few server configuration suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISP domain would work you just need to know the domain you want to filter out.

You can also set a custom filter and not use the predefined one which would let you filter out hostname.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Analytics**

Filtering the traffic in Google Analytics is not retroactive with Web Filters when you're in the Administration tab. So any traffic that's already happened would not be filtered from your current result sets. That being said, to be productive, you can [create a Custom Report](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/custom-reports.html) that doesn't show any of the traffic from the bot based on a few things. You can make it exclude a specific browser version like:

```
exclude > Browser Version > Exact > BadBot
```

You can also use custom filters for IP ranges and you can even filter out traffic from specific countries or restrict traffic to your own country (if that's who your site targets).

**Stopping it on the [web] server itself**

In regard to protecting the web server, the same rules apply (for instance if the traffic is all referral traffic from `badexample.com`).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^badexample.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

You can [block by IP ranges and reverse domain look-ups in Apache using Deny directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#host).

```
Deny from 192.168.205
Deny from badexample.com
Deny from de
```

You can [block them using Environment Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env):

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent BadBot GoAway=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=GoAway
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a bot scraping your site, are you sure they are even executing JavaScript?

All requests should pass an IP address, although it could be a proxy instead of the actual source.

Comment: It's probably a bit more than a bot to be honest, the JavaScript is def firing and the traffic is huge. This domain comes in as a new visit on every hit. Massively driving our traffic. The sys Admins can find the domain but that's it. The domain is gpotato.net, having googled it a few other sites have had this issue.

Comment: Is gpotato.net the referrer to your site? gPotato is a Chinese based online gaming company, it appears that they may be sending you traffic that you shouldnt be getting.

Comment: Yep, scrapes the site once a month for 5 days, around 2000 visits a day and then stops. Dev team are struggling to block so need a filter.

Comment: If this is a referrer, then the source might involve multiple IP addresses. You should be able to add the domain to the referral exclusion list. Or you should be able to use a filter if you are not on universal analytics.

Comment: Its not a refer though, which is why this is strange. There is no referral path connected. Its purely the network domain.

Comment: Do you have access to a sampling of the log files with this traffic?